# How can I attach x.509v3 certificate at request soap web services

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, request

I should to call a Soap web services from local WSDL. To call this web service, I must attach a X.509v3 certificate in my request.

So I have this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    try { 
    //certificato 509v3
    string pathCertificato = @"C:\Users\michele.castriotta\Desktop\Certificati\keystore_healt.pfx";
    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(pathCertificato), "password");

    PianoAssistenzialeResidenzialeService.PianoAssistenzialeResidenzialeClient ws_Client = 
        new PianoAssistenzialeResidenzialeService.PianoAssistenzialeResidenzialeClient();



    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

Now, how can I attach certificate in client request?